Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 because of The following packages have been kept back libpq5
Tried everything sudo update/upgrade, etc. and continue to get the message
"The following packages have been kept back: libpq5"
Therefore I cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 either from the command line or the Software Updater.  Please help.

Please edit your question and include the full output of the terminal commands apt policy libpq5 and sudo apt update

The libpq5 package is being kept back by a routine phased update. You can override libpq5 being being kept back by a phased update by manually installing it with sudo apt install libpq5 Then your release upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 can proceed normally.
Unfortunately trying to install libpq5 generated an unmet dependencies: libpq5 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages error. Visit Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Here you have two alternatives.

Try to install libpq5 anyway in your broken package management scenario.

(more interesting) Try to safely uninstall the broken packages that are preventing you from installing libpq5 if they are not essential packages, so that your Ubuntu will stop complaining that it needs the libpq5 package to be able to upgrade to 24.04. This circumvents the broken packages problem which is most likely caused by a non-default software source line in your /etc/apt/sources.list file which should be commented out by starting  that line with a # character and after that run sudo apt update to update your sources.list file.



Tried sudo apt install libpq5 as suggested by @karel but got the following message.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpq5 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Visit Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Here you have two alternatives. 1. Try to install libpq5 anyway in your broken package management scenario. 2. (more interesting) Try to safely uninstall the broken packages if they are not essential so that your Ubuntu will stop complaining that it needs the libpq5 package to be able to upgrade to 24.04.
